# How to get values from mapping table in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have created one domain class in grails which have mapping to vehicleList as per mentioned in code. Now I want to get list of vehicles with family id = 1. I can get this using `familyInstance.vehicleList`.

But I want to know is there any other way I can get this. I tried to apply criteria but for both `createCriteria` and `withCriteria` showing me error `arrayIndexOutOfBound` error in projections where I have mentioned `property("vehicleList")`. Applying basic MySql query I can directly get data from mapping table but If I want to get those data using criteria how to do that.

```
class Family {

    String name

    Integer noOfVehicle

    List vehicleList

    static hasMany = [vehicleList: String]

    static constraints = {
    }
}



class FamilyController {

 def edit(Family familyInstance) {

        def fi = familyInstance
        println "familyInstance ::: " + familyInstance

        //Try 1
        def familyCriteria = Family.createCriteria()
        def vehicleList = familyCriteria.list{
            createAlias('vehicleList','vlist')
            projections {
                property('vehicleList')
            }
            eq('id',familyInstance.id)
        }
        println "vehicleList ::: " + vehicleList

        //Try 2
        def vehicleList1 = familyInstance.vehicleList
        println "vehicleList1 ::: " + vehicleList1

        //Try 3
        def vehicleList2 = Family.withCriteria{
            createAlias('vehicleList','vlist')
            projections{
                property('vehicleList')
            }
            eq('id',familyInstance.id)
        }
        println "vehicleList2 ::: ===------>>>>>" + vehicleList2
        respond familyInstance
    }
}
```

Database structure:

[image]

[Error with projections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SRbN.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `createAlias` statement

```
Family.createCriteria().list{
    projections {
        property('vehicleList')
    }
    eq('id', familyInstance.id)
}
```

works

Comment: If I remove it. its still showing me error.
URI
/SampleGrailsProject/family/edit/1
Class
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
Message
0

Comment: Then something else is going on. I tested that exact code in an example project

Comment: If I comment property('vehicleList') then I won't show me error. but Its not working with property in projections. I have added error screenshot in question.